# 手を差し伸べる vs 手伝う vs 助ける

Tags: word-choice

Are there any differences between 手を差し伸べる, 手伝う and 助ける? They all mean "I will help you". In which situations would I use each of them?

Answer (score 2):

Very much different in their nuances.

手を差し伸べる -- start helping someone who is desperate.
例)　マリアは祈るだけでなく難民の生活に手を差し伸べた

手伝う -- general 'help'
例)　マリアは皿洗いを手伝った

助ける -- save, rescue and help something.
例)　消防士は瀕死のマリアを助けた

Use them carefully with looking up you dictionary. Some Japanese dictionaries provide you some collocations.
See also 支える

Comment: `general 'help'` はちょっと曖昧すぎるので "assist/support" とかにした方がいいかも…

Comment: 手を差し伸べるって必死の状況でしか使わんつわけ？

Comment: @Newbie, この中では、一番被救助者が一人ではどうにもならない状況にあります  https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%89%8B%E3%82%92%E5%B7%AE%E3%81%97%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B

Comment: @naruto, don't worry my english sucks.